# manipulation of column and row on bootstrap in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have two rows and three columns like this

> [1] [2] [3]
>
> [4] [5] [6]

I want they look like this when I change to mobile view

> [1] [2]
>
> [3] [4]
>
> [5] [6]

I've tried it, but when I change to mobile view, they turn out like this

> [1] [2]
>
> [3]
>
> [4] [5]
>
> [6]

how to manipulate row and column?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, you are using two rows that's why you are getting this result. Put all of them in **one row** and add **clearfixes** for special sizes.

```
<!-- columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">2</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div> <!-- It works on mobile view -->

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">3</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div> <!-- It works on desktop view -->

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">4</div>

  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div> <!-- It works on mobile view -->

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">5</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">6</div>
</div>
```

Now, you will have:

[1] [2] [3]

[4] [5] [6]

for desktop view and

[1] [2]

[3] [4]

[5] [6]

for mobile view.

Comment: hi @kaan btw how to implement to rails? I had problem when I use it in rails. how to put the `<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>` and `<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>` ? should I put them into loop? check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046895/how-to-implement-style-in-html-col-to-rails/37048149#37048149) for my view code. thx